# JavaFx/ Swing window does not open after update to Java 1.8u40

Tags: java, swing, javafx

We have an javafx application developed mainly in `java 1.7` and tested in `1.8`. It was running fine until `java 1.8u35`. Now we discovered, JavaFx windows are not going to open in `1.8u40` after upgrade. Even worse, the modal windows are blocking the entire tab/ browser of being used. So the user is just able to close the browser using the task manager.

We use `javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel` to embed jfx-code into swing legacy code.

I have completely no clue what might be the problem, as there are no errors displayed in client's java console.

**UPDATE:**

I reviewed the known issues list for `java1.8` [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-known-issues-2157115.html#A999961). The only thing I would probably link to our issue is this bug:

> BUG-RT-32597: The SwingNode class does not support High DPI displays.

So I tried lowering the screen resolution (1280x1024 to 800x600) but without success.

Does anyone faced a similar issue before and knows what might help?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to better track down the problem but with not much luck.
To make it more visible, this is basically whats going on on window loading:

```
public static void initWindow(JDialog dialog){

    final JFXPanel jfx = new JFXPanel();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("JFXPanel");
        }
    });

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane;
            //... do some content loading

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,width,height);
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    };

    dialog.add(jfx);
    System.out.println("added jfx panel.");

    dialog.pack();
    System.out.println("packed jfx panel.");

    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    System.out.println("loaded.");
```

}

I thought execution is going to stop somewhere, but its running through the entire function as usual. Nevertheless the window is not showing up.

**UPDATE:**

Not completely correct, my last comment, as I found out:

Around the above function, the following happens:

```
initWindow(this); //this is extending java.swing.JDialog
System.out.println("this comment is printed to console");
super.setVisible(true); //this is not executed properly. if removed, browser will not be blocked, but window doesnt show up either
System.out.println("this comment is not printed to console";
```

So, in general, there is the JDialog which gets packed with a JfxPanel. When calling setVisible() method from the JDialog class, the Application gets blocked but the window doesnt show up. Actually, in the thumbnail screen (alt+tab) it is shown as a container inside the application.

When removing the setVisible call, the browser does not get blocked, but also the window does not show up. Unfortunately, I did not find the JDialog class code to look up, what's going on inside setVisible().

Any ideas, what might be wrong with our setup or the setVisible method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem. While comparing the Java sources of 1.8.0_31 and 1.8.0_45 we found out that there were some changes in the `JFXPanel` source code introduced with 1.8.0_45 that may cause problems in the following situation:

1. initialize modal `JDialog` with `JFXPanel` (executed on Swing's EDT)
2. initialize and set FX scene on `JFXPanel` in FX task (executed on FX Thread)
3. wait for FX task to be finished (wait on EDT)
4. `pack()` and `show()` `JDialog` (continued on EDT, blocks program execution)
5. continue with program execution after user closed `JDialog` (on EDT)

We use this workflow in order to wait for some user input being shown in a new modal `JDialog` and continue normal programm execution on EDT afterwards.

In 1.8.0_31, the preferred size of `JFXPanel` seems to be set in FX thread which allows `JDialog.pack()` to determine the correct bounds.

In 1.8.0_45, the preferred size of JFXPanel seems to be set not in FX thread anymore but in EDT after all pending AWT events are executed. So, when (4) is executed, `JDialog.pack()` does not know about the preferred size of the scene. As a consequence, the dialog has no content, or does not show up if undecorated as described in the original question above.

Here is a complete example to reproduce the different behaviour:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // create JDialog on EDT
            final JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JDialog)null, "JDialog");

            // initialize FX platform and create JFXPanel
            final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

            // add resize listener for JFXPanel
            jfxPanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    // not called in 1.8.0_45
                    System.out.println("JFXPanel.getSize(): "+jfxPanel.getSize());
                }
            });

            // set FX Scene on JFXPanel and wait until finished
            runAndWait(new Runnable() {                
                public void run() {
                    Text text = TextBuilder.create().text("JavaFx content").y(20).build();
                    Group root = new Group(text);
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
                }
            });

            // show undecorated modal JDialog with FX content
            System.out.println("JFXPanel.getPreferredSize(): "+jfxPanel.getPreferredSize());
            dialog.setUndecorated(true);
            dialog.add(jfxPanel);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setModal(true);
            System.out.println("JDialog.setVisible()");
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private static void runAndWait(Runnable r) {
    try {
        FutureTask<Object> task = new FutureTask<Object>(r, null);
        Platform.runLater(task);
        task.get();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

When running this program, `componentResized()` is called only in 1.8.0_31 but not in 1.8.0_45.

A possible fix while keeping the synchronous program workflow on EDT is to replace `JDialog.pack()` with `JDialog.setSize(...)`, e. g. by setting a constant size or by using the size of the FX scene that could be determined using `root.getBoundsInLocal()`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same behaviour described by @Peter using 1.8.0_121.

I was able to get dialog.pack() to work using a window listener.

```
dialog.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        ((JDialog)e.getSource()).pack();
    }    
});
```